# Azure DevOps server how to make certain group available for all projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

Initially we were using only one project and multiple security groups have been created on this project level. Recently we have created multiple projects and would like to reuse the same security groups for those projects. Is it possible to reuse the security group that has been created initially in project X for the rest of the projects, otherwise I need to recreated basically the same groups and later on keep those groups in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such method could directly add the project level security group from one project to another.

For example: Security Group : Project A -> Project B

But you could control the Project A's Security Group permission in Project B.

Step1: Search the Project A's Security Group  in Project B.

[image]

Step2: You could select the Security Group and change the permissions for Project B.

In this case, users in this security group will get the permissions of Project B, but the Group will not show in the group list.

You could use this workaround instead of creating a new group.